# Sending multiple embeds at once

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to send multiple embeds (more specifically, just 2) at once when a user enters a certain  command. The reason being is that the information I want to print would look horrendously long in just 1 embed. I've heard this can only be done using webhooks as the discord API does not usually allow this. So the following code won't work:

```
const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
.setAuthor("blah")
.addField("blah")
message.channel.send({embed}) // this will send fine

const embed2 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
.setAuthor("blah")
.addField("blah")
message.channel.send({embed2});   // This wont work
```

I'm also using rich embeds as you can see, but I don't think that has any effect on what I'm trying to do. I have tried looking up how to properly use a webhook to do this, but I've barely even managed to just declare my hook. I'd appreciate it if I could get help on just how I'd go about doing what I'm trying to accomplish (and if there actually IS a way to do this without using a webhook, by all means I'd love to hear it!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can send multiple embeds to the same channel, I'm not sure who told you it's not possible. Here's the code I'm using, which successfully sends multiple embeds to a channel:

```
function send2Embeds(message) {
    let channel = message.channel;

    // next create rich embeds
    let embed1 = new Discord.RichEmbed({
        title: 'embed1',
        description: 'description1',
        author: {
            name: 'author1'
        }
    });

    let embed2 = new Discord.RichEmbed({
        title: 'embed2',
        description: 'description2',
        author: {
            name: 'author2'
        }
    });

    // send embed to channel
    channel.send(embed1)
    .then(msg => {
        // after the first is sent, send the 2nd (makes sure it's in the correct order)
        channel.send(embed2);
    });
}
```

As you can see, I wait for the first embed to be sent successfully & for the promise to return before sending the second embed. Are you running into errors while trying things like this?

Comment: Oh, it worked this way! It didn't work when I tried doing using the methods like .addfield etc. It said I was trying to send an empty message. I'm in the discord.js discord server and I tried searching "sending multiple embeds" in the questions channel, and literally EVERY response said that you have to use webhooks. So either there is a miscommunication with what I'm trying to do and they're talking about, or they were all wrong. Either way, thank you, this does what I need it to do.

Comment: @SirOxorsid - aah weird, maybe you need to add a `title` or `description` instead of just `author` and `field`? Glad this helped!

Answer (score -2):

I think it would be better if you used:

```
message.channel.send(embed1, embed2)
```